# Sending data to the chosen client in my Server

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm learning socket programming and i want when that clients are connected to my server. I can send data to them with their specific address..

e.g

Server ---> client 1

╚---> client 2

╚---> client 3

Connection from: 192.168.5.3

Connection from: 192.168.5.10

Connection from: 192.168.5.15

For example say client 1 sends data to me and then client 2 also sends data to me i want to reply back only to client 1 how could i possibly to do that?..

How will i store my client so when i need to send data to them i know which client will i send data to?

Here's my Code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define TRUE             1
#define FALSE            0

typedef struct SERVER_FD{

int sPort;
int serverFD;
int smaxFD; 
int newFD;



}sSD;
pid_t pid, sid;
int cFD, 
    dSize, 
    err, 
    start = 1,
    state,
    DescRead,
    DCSERVER = FALSE;

int fd;
char buf[255];
int nbytes; 


struct sockaddr_in  addr, cli_addr;
unsigned long ip;
char strbuf[256];
socklen_t clilen;
fd_set fdin, fduse;
struct pollfd pfds[2];
int rc;

void process(int ServerFD, int Port, int sMax, int NewSFD);
void cleanUP(int i, int max);
void dlogs(unsigned long ip);

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sSD link;
    sSD *sCon;
    sCon = &link;
    sCon->sPort = 53234;

    fd = open("/tmp/myFIFO", O_RDWR);
        if(fd == -1) {
        printf("Could not open the pipe\n");
    }

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,
fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | 
O_NONBLOCK);


   sCon->serverFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sCon->serverFD != -1)
   {
    err = setsockopt(sCon->serverFD, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&start, sizeof(start));
      if (err != -1)
            {
                err = ioctl(sCon->serverFD, FIONBIO, (char *)&start);

                    if (err != -1){

                    process(sCon->serverFD,sCon->sPort,sCon->smaxFD,sCon->newFD);


                    }
                            else{

                        perror("ioctl() failed");
                            close(sCon->serverFD);
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                        }
            }

                    else{

              perror("setsockopt() failed");
                close(sCon->serverFD);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
   }
       else{
       perror("FAILED CONNECTING TO SOCKET");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   } 

}

void process(int ServerFD, int Port, int sMax, int NewSFD){



   bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof(addr));

   addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
   addr.sin_port        = htons(Port);

   err = bind(ServerFD,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
   if (err < 0)
   {
      perror("bind() failed");
      close(ServerFD);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


   err = listen(ServerFD, 32);
   if (err < 0)
   {
      perror("listen() failed");
      close(ServerFD);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);


   FD_ZERO(&fdin);
   sMax = ServerFD;
   FD_SET(ServerFD, &fdin);



   do
   {

        fduse = fdin;

      //printf("Waiting on select()...\n");
      err = select(sMax + 1, &fduse, NULL, NULL, NULL);

      if (err < 0)
      {
     perror("  select() failed");
     break;
      }

      DescRead = err;
      for (cFD=0; cFD <= sMax  &&  DescRead > 0; ++cFD)
      {

     if (FD_ISSET(cFD, &fduse))
     {

        DescRead -= 1;


        if (cFD == ServerFD)
        {
           //printf("  Listening socket is readable\n");

           do
           {

              NewSFD = accept(ServerFD,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
              if (NewSFD < 0)
              {
                 if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                 {
                    perror("  accept() failed");
                    DCSERVER = TRUE;
                 }
                 break;
              }
                ip = ntohl(cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
                printf("  Connection from %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
                    (int)(ip>>24)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>16)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>8)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>0)&0xff);
                    dlogs(ip);

              FD_SET(NewSFD, &fdin);
              if (NewSFD > sMax)
                 sMax = NewSFD;

           } while (NewSFD != -1);


        }

        else
        {
           //printf("  Descriptor %d is readable\n", cFD);
          pfds[0].fd = fd;
          pfds[0].events = POLLIN;
          pfds[1].fd = cFD;
          pfds[1].events = POLLIN;
          state = FALSE;


           do
           {
            rc = poll(pfds, 2, -1);

            if (pfds[0].revents & POLLIN)
             {
              while ((nbytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1)) > 0)
               {
                   buf[nbytes] = '\0';
                     printf("%s\n", buf);
                   }


              pfds[0].events = 0;
              pfds[1].events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;

               }

            if (pfds[1].revents & POLLIN)
            {
              err = recv(cFD, strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), 0);
              if (err < 0)
              {
                 if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                 {
                    perror("  recv() failed");
                    state = TRUE;

                 }
                 break;
              }

               if (err == 0)
              {
                 printf("  Connection closed\n");
                 state = TRUE;

                 break;
              }
              dSize = err;
             printf("  %d bytes received\n", dSize);
            }

            if (pfds[1].revents & POLLOUT)
            {
                err = send(cFD, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
              if (err < 0)
              {
                 perror("  send() failed");
                 state = TRUE;

                 break;
              }
                pfds[0].events = POLLIN;
                pfds[1].events = POLLIN;
            }


           } while (TRUE);

           fopen("/sockF.txt","w");
           if (state)
           {

              close(cFD);
              FD_CLR(cFD, &fdin);
              if (cFD == sMax)
              {
                 while (FD_ISSET(sMax, &fdin) == FALSE)
                    sMax -= 1;
              }
           }
        } 
     } 
      } 

   } while (DCSERVER == FALSE);

    cleanUP(cFD, sMax);

}

void cleanUP(int i, int max){

for (i=0; i <= max; ++i)
   {
     if (FD_ISSET(i, &fdin))
     close(i);
   }

}

void dlogs(unsigned long ip){

FILE* pFile = fopen("/sockF.txt", "w+");

fprintf(pFile,"Connection from: %d.%d.%d.%d",
                    (int)(ip>>24)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>16)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>8)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>0)&0xff);

fclose(pFile);

}
```

Clients can connect to me but i don't know which of them to send data when both of them are connected... I can send data when only 1 client is connected to my server but how will i send data to another client when 2 of my client is connected at the same time?

Thanks,

Comment: First of all, please read http://sscce.org/, the code you posted is way to much. You don't have to post all code in your questions, only the relevant parts. You can always add a link to the full code on e.g. http://ideone.com/ or http://pastebin.com/ or similar service.

Comment: As for your problem, you need to keep track of all connected clients. It's common to use a structure in an array or linked list, with the structure containing the file descriptor of the client socket, as well as buffers for input received from the client, and output to send to the client.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info.. Can you show me a sample how can i store the socket in a structure?..

Comment: There are enormous amounts of example client-server code on the Internet, ranging from simple tutorials to advanced usage. Please try to search for simple chat server tutorials, it should be a good beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - i would say it is not well written. But since you are learning you need to understand which piece of code is doing what.

```
NewSFD = accept(ServerFD,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

NewSFD is the resultant new *connected descriptor/socket to only the client* which sent you the message. If you do a write/send on this descriptor/socket, *it will be received by the sending client.*

```
char * response = "Connection echoed";
send(NewSFD, response, strlen(response), 0); // call returns number of bytes written.
```

If you want to do it at some point latter, you need to save this socket in some struct and access it to write to the specific client.

cli_addr would actually return the client info such as port and ip, which could be used to create a new socket latter. However, you are using tcp which requires a handshake through connect and accept calls. So using the saved connected socket is the appropriate choice.

You can use a struct like this

```
typedef struct _client_fds{
    int connected_sock; // copy the returned value of accept sock_addr_in cli_addr;
    struct sock_add_in cli_addr // copy the client struct here
} client_fds;
```

client_fds Clients[MAX];

and latter retrieve socket to write from it

Comment: Yes it's not well written, sorry about that.. How can i make my code more optimize?.. and also im using pipes to send data to the client the server reads from this pipe and output it to the client. how can i store the socket in a struct?.. can you show me sample code?

Comment: Well it seems like a big mess. Who is submitting data through pipes to server? Seems like a 3rd entity. Normally select or poll are alternate mechanisms to monitor a set of descriptors when you don't know which one sends data when. You are kind of using select for receiving at server and poll for again reading some data at server which i am not sure of the reason. Just make an array of sockets and copy all accepted sockets there. You need a way to track which one to access for which client so you might create socket:client ip/port struct.

Comment: QUestion is, why do you need that? Why don't you simply respond right after the accept call? If you are using select or poll it will tell you every time when data is available. Here is one select based tutorial i wrote a while back http://forum.codecall.net/topic/64205-concurrent-tcp-server-using-select-api-in-linux-c/ containing code too though you would find many.

Comment: Well the pipe is controlled by a website the website sends data to the pipe then the server reads the pipe when there is data on it then it sends it down to the client. I did that because I'll be using that to control a device which is the client.. Commands will be sent to the pipe, server reads it and send it down to the chosen device/client.

Comment: Which means there is no correlation between when data is received and when it is sent. You would send data from server when it is available in pipe. All you need is a currently connected. So then go on with making an array or a struct array of clientip/port:socket and upon receiving data from pipe, go through this array and pick your destination. Alternately, if you have a way of creating a joint data structure i.e. which contains the client connected socket and the pipe info, you receive data from pipe and write it on the socket present with in the same struct. Just check that socket is valid

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to create a struct array of clientip/port:socket .. Can u light my way in creating that?.. I'll do the rest. thanks.

Comment: typedef struct _client_fds{

 int connected_sock; // copy the returned value of accept
 sock_addr_in cli_addr; // copy the client struct here
} client_fds;

client_fds Clients[MAX]; // MAX could be like 100 or whatever maximum clients you expect to have
Loop through this struct when you need to send data. Or better add a field pipe in the struct above. So when you reach the pipe to receive the corresponding socket is what you write upon and avoiding looping to find the destination.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help... this may sound stupid but what is a field pipe?

Comment: I meant the pipe array that you are reading from at the server. It will actually be an array like in your existing code. But i meant to group them together with the socket so you no longer have to search for socket to write upon

Comment: What i used is named pipe mkfifo.. I already completed the code that gets the file descriptor of every new accept.. thank you for your help. but im still confused how will i add my pipe in the struct above?

Comment: In that case you store a string showing path to mkfifo. mkfifo creates a named pipe stored on the file system. Unless you really need to be on permanent storage and accessible from any process, i won't use it and would prefer http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe which is in memory and can be shared between only parents and children

Comment: Yes i'll be using the mkfifo because i'll be on permanent storage.. this is how it is: the website writes to the c program where the c program writes to the pipe and the server reads the pipe and send down the command to the device/client.